# jquery isotope version 2 message if no result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-isotope

I am using jquery isotope, to filter results, as:

```
      <div class="isotope">
      <div class="filter-item">1</div>
      <div class="filter-item">2</div>
      <div class="filter-item">3</div>
      </div>
```

JS Code:

```
      <script>
      $( function() {
      var $container = $('.isotope');
      if ( !$container.data('isotope').filteredItems.length ) {
      $container.html("Sorry.No result");
      }
      </script>
```

I am trying to display - Message, if no results in filter process.
But its not working, any clues ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use this with isotope 'arrangeComplete' event:

```
$container.on( 'arrangeComplete', function( event, filteredItems ) {
        var resultCount = filteredItems.length;
        if(resultCount == 0) {
            $container.html("Sorry.No result");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Works on first click, but when I click another button which should have items, still "Sorry. No result" is shown. It does not disappear anymore.

Answer (score 2):

You need to actually check if the length has a value.

```
if ( $container.data('isotope').filteredItems.length > 0)
```

You are missing the '>0' so will always get a truthy value. Also remove the !.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a while trying to get this to work in Vanilla JS and thought I'd share my working solution for anyone else trying to do a "No results found" message without Jquery:

```
// ...after buttonclick detected
// set filter for Isotope
   iso.arrange({ filter: filterValue });
// No results check
    var noResults = document.querySelector('.no-results');
    
    if (iso.filteredItems.length == 0) {
      noResults.classList.add('visible');
    }
    else {
      noResults.classList.remove('visible');
    }
```